# App Engine. Querying Every Other Minute

Tags: python, google-app-engine

In google app engine I am storing sensor data coming in once a minute. So for 24 hours that's a total of 1,440 individual readings. This means I'm bumping up against the maximum limit of 1,000 results for all queries.

Unless someone can show me a way to access all 1,440 readings in sequential order, I'm okay with this right now. I would like to just query 720 readings, or every other minute.

The readings are stored as a DateTime object, ex. 2011-03-24 02:01:00.

What's the best way to write this query?

I was using:

```
day_start = datetime(2011, 03, 24)
day_end = day_start + timedelta(days=1)
readings = models.Log.all()
readings.filter('dateTime >=', day_start)
readings.filter('dateTime <', day_end)
```

How would I change this to only query every other minute?

Comment: are you aware that the 1000 maximum limit was removed months ago?

Comment: Ah... Okay, In the Development Console, the Datastore View only shows results 1 - 10 of 1000. Between this and previous threads I had assumed this still held. Adding a counter to my results I see you're right. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fetch all results using cursors:

```
    q = parse.YourModel.gql(YourQuery)
    tlist = []
    tl = q.fetch(1000)
    cursor = q.cursor()
    while len(tl) > 0:
        tlist.extend(tl)
        q = parse.YourModel.gql(YourQuery)
        q.with_cursor(cursor)
        tl = q.fetch(1000)
        cursor = q.cursor()
```

`tlist` will contain all results up to limit of variable size (32MB).

Comment: Thanks. That helps my understanding of the cursor quite a bit. I did find out from systempuntoout that the 1000 limit was removed.

Comment: There's no limit on variable size.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do something like this using gql .

```
models.Log.gql("WHERE dateTime >= :1 AND dateTime  < :2", day_start,day_end)
```